Is there any impact on the candidate selection during election with open list systems comparing postal voting to polling stations?
After the 2024 European Parliament election (with an Open list party proportional system in Austria) I have heard from several people in Austria independently from each other that they found Postal voting more pleasant because, in contrast to Polling station at home, they had more time to look at the individual MPs on the Internet. They found it an advantage of postal voting that they could make a more informed choice.
I can well imagine that the threshold, especially for people who are not very interested in politics, is too high to sit down and go through the names on their own. This threshold is greatly reduced by postal voting because they have to read through how voting works anyway.
Now I would be interested to know whether this can be backed up with figures and facts. Hence my question: Is there research on the topic if there is any impact on the candidate selection during election with open list party proportional system comparing postal voting to polling stations?

Just for completeness, it should be mentioned that i. e. some German states try to accomodate this and send the ballots for local elections by mail to all voters some days before election day. All voters can study the ballots and make panachage decisions at home. Whether they send back the ballots by mail or bring them personally to the polling station remains their decision.

@ccprog Here in Massachusetts we do that for elections that have propositions that voters vote on, as these mailings include explanations of all the questions along with statements from the proponents and opponents of each question. But we don't do the same thing for candidates for offices, we expect the media to publish interviews, etc.

@Barmar Not a comparable case. This is about an election with 10 or more parties, each fielding between 10 and 20 candidates, and each voter having 30 votes to distribute (OK, that is the extreme case of the Stuttgart city council, but I have been told that even for mid-size cities the ballot might take the form of a booklet just to list all the candidates.)

@ccprog Ouch. I don't even bother voting for my local Town Meeting representative because I have no idea who any of them are.
